# mutt: color messages with attachments differently

Tags: mutt

I tried this:

```
folder-hook . 'color index green black "~B \"Content-disposition: attachment;\""'
```

but got nothing except exceptionally slow rendering of the inbox.

Is there any way to do this, or generally anything that will allow me to see messages with attachments in the index (flags etc..) that can be solved by configuration and not patching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
color index green black "~X 1-"
```

That is match message with 1 or more attachments.

works with my version of `mutt` ([mutt-patched 1.5.21-5nntp1](http://www.llucax.com.ar/proj/mutt-nntp-debian/index.html)) though it looks like it's available in the vanilla version from `mutt.org` as well and has first been introduced in `1.5.12` released in September 2005.

It's going to be slow in any case, because to find out about attachments, you have to read the body (so that means the emails will have to be downloaded). Or you can use Dennis solution that gives a good approximation in most cases.

Comment: Which distribution is this? Or where can the exact sources be found? Without that information, your answer tells little.

Comment: That actually works, in version 1.5.21 (2010-09-15). Although the thing is very slow, which I don't understand since I am running it on with 8CPUs and 8 GB RAM...

Comment: What does ~X signifies ? It says "References" field ?

Answer (score 2):

Why not do `~H \"Content-type: multipart/mixed\"`? That way it doesn't need to look at the body of each message.

A completely statistically bogus sample of a handful of my messages is that multipart/mixed is used for messages with attachments, and multipart/alternative for messages that have an html and plain text variant but no attachments.

Comment: ITYM `~h` instead of `~H`. Note that it will miss at least the signed messages with attachments.

Comment: and with big T in type. This is *very* slow, way slower then ~X.